# Why would a field *not* be considered a discrete valuation ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There are two theorems in Matsumura (p. 78-9)

> **Theorem 11.1** Let $R$ be a valuation ring. Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (1) $R$ is a DVR
>
> (2) $R$ is a PID
>
> (3) $R$ is Noetherian

and

> **Theorem 11.2** Let $R$ be a ring; then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (1) $R$ is a DVR
>
> (2) $R$ is a local PID, and not a field
>
> (3) $R$ is a Noetherian local ring, dim $R >0$ and the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_R$ is principal
>
> (4) $R$ is a one-dimensional normal Noetherian local ring.

**Question**

Suppose we have a field $K$. Then $K$ is trivially a valuation ring. It is also (of course) a PID, then according to Thereorem 11.1 it must be a DVR.

Since $K$ is a DVR, $K$ is not a field according to 11.2. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user26857 Matsumura himself says that fields are valuation rings. On page 71, he says "The case R=K is the trivial valuation ring".

Comment: I think you're referring to me, not user26857. I made a mistake and misinterpreted his definition as I admitted in the next comment. My apologies.

Comment: @Weaam I was actually writing to both of you but I can only refer to one. user26857 said he didn't want to argue with Matsumura about whether or not fields were valuation rings...so I just wanted to state Matsumura's opinion.

Comment: I think the author some how assume (without saying clearly) that *from now on we will only talk about non-trivial valuation rings.* I'm saying this because just before Theorem 11.1 the following definition was given: *a valuation ring whose value group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ is called a discrete valuation ring (DVR).* so the Theorem 11.1 doesn't make sense unless you discard the trivial case (i.e. field).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of DVRs in Matsumura, as valuation rings whose value group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, doesn't allow you to consider the fields as DVRs.

Comment: Succinctly: a valuation ring is a field iff its value group is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Following the definitions of the book:

A field is a valuation ring, yet not a DVR, since its valuation group is not ismorphic to the integers, as pointed out in another answer already.

Thus, there is in fact a contradiction there. Indeed, there is a glitch in Theorem 11.1. In the proof, part  (2) implies (1), it is assumed (implictly) that the PID is not a field.